# How to detect touch events with Firefox 48.0

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-canvas, touch-event

I am trying to create and understand touch events using this [**tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events). Here the demo is done on my touch enabled desktop PC (HP Pavillon all-in-one) and Firefox 48.0. However, the touches don't get detected.

I can click the button which says initialized in the Log but when I touch the canvas area, it won't get recognized.

I tried this [**solution**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25024197/how-to-make-sure-touch-events-are-enabled-in-firefox-desk-top-browser) and set the `dom.w3c_touch_events.enabled` to `1` and `2`.

Then I tried including a script, this [**one**](https://willowsystems.github.io/jSignature/#/about/) which works completely fine. It detects the touches and I can scribble with my finger on it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: do you get any errors in the developer tools console?

Comment: no errors form the console, and the same demo works fine in Chomre (but I do want to use Firefox)

Comment: to be clear, are you saying the code in the first link works in Chrome but not Firefox

Comment: exactly, this demo here http://jsfiddle.net/Darbicus/z3Xdx/10/ runs only in Chrome, and I already reinstalled Firefox, etc.

Comment: My only touch device is a phone, and it's still on 47 (and it works) - did this work in 47?

Comment: nope, did not, updated after

Comment: how strange that MDN example works on chrome but not firefox (except that it does work on mobile firefox)

Comment: I'm guessing it must be the firefox, any idea wether I should change more of the settings?